# Sorting special name to end in database

Tags: mysql

I want to sort a mysql-table

```
select id,name from tbl order by name asc;
```

returns

```
1  name1
2  name2
4  name3
5  name4
8  name5
```

How to order that e.g name 3 goes to end of the table like

```
select id,name from tbl order by ["name is name3????"],name asc;
```

returns

```
1  name1
2  name2
5  name4
8  name5
4  name3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `case` you can return a value based on a condition. So you can return 1 for `name3` and 0 for other names. Primarily sort on this value to put name3 in the back. The secondary sort value is the name, so that the other names are still sorted alphabetically.

```
select 
  id, name 
from 
  tbl 
order by 
  case when name = 'name3' then 1 else 0 end,
  name
```

Strawberry just taught me in the comment that you could also use the function [`field`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php) to accomplish this. This is especially handy and more compact, if you want to specify a specific sort for a number of names. Using `case` that would quickly become bulky. `Field` returns the index of the first string in the list of other strings, so `field(name, 'name3', 'name4')` would return 1 for 'name3' and 2 for 'name4' and 0 for all other names.

Your query would then look like this:

```
select 
  id, name 
from 
  tbl 
order by 
  field(name, 'name3'),
  name
```

Comment: @Strawberry - You mean [FIELD()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php)? Great, I didn't know about that function, but if I understand correctly, you could change my query to `order by field(name, 'name3'), name`. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: No, I meant FIELD() !?!? ;-)